# Azure DevOps Git Granular Trigger Build for Continuous Integration & Delivery

Tags: git, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have inherited a somewhat strange git repo that is structured as follows:

```
Some Client - Programme/
├── ClientName.Thing1/
│   ├── ClientName.Thing1.sln
│   └── ClientName.Thing1.ProjectX/
│       ├── ClientName.Thing1.ProjectX.csproj
│       ├── file1.cs
│       └── file2.cs
└── ClientName.Thing2/
    ├── ClientName.Thing2.sln
    ├── ClientName.Thing2.ProjectY/
    │   ├── ClientName.Thing2.ProjectY.csproj
    │   ├── file3.cs
    │   └── file4.cs
    └── ClientName.Thing2.ProjectZ/
        ├── ClientName.Thing2.ProjectZ.csproj
        ├── file5.cs
        └── file6.cs
```

So essentially, i have a single repo, that contains a bunch of folders; `ClientName.Thing1, ClientName.Thing2, etc..` and all of the code exists below these top level folders..

Workflow seems to be Person-A works on `ClientName.Thing2` and Person-B works on `ClientName.Thing1` at a time, independently... both can be opened in Visual Studio with the *.sln file.

What this means though, is that although they are both sort-of working on different areas.. they can "cross-pollinate" as it all comes from the same `master` branch, and technically Person-A even though they are not meant to, could edit something in the "area" of work that Person-B is looking at..

This is not the biggest issue though, the biggest issue is actually releasing things, and specifically getting a build of the aspect that you want to release. There's not really compiled code (python, sql, etc.) and therefore it is possible to 'get away' with simply connecting to the repo in CICD pipeline and deploying the stuff.. without a build, which i find a bit annoying... it means you can't guarantee that you are always deploying the same thing to each environment.

So, to the question!

Is there a way, that if Person-A commits some changes to *anything* that sits under `ClientName.Thing2` folder, for it to trigger a build only for a specific build definition??

Right now... i can only see a way to trigger on a commit into the repo as a whole which will be super super noisy!

Answer (score 0):

Add a [path filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) to your build definition's CI trigger.

Comment: ok, so that was significantly easier than i was expecting! will give it a whirl 